# Require is not a function discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was coding an event handler (by Codelyon) but I ran into a new error. Here it is

```
C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:10
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
                                    ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:10:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:9:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

My main coding is here. (main.js)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler','event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
});







client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

I have all the necessary packages (along with others like images-scraper).
For my events, I have message and ready. (Ready tells me when my bot is running and message senses when the commands are said). I also have some commands. Tell me if you need the coding in those.
Here's the coding for my event handler:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const load_dir = (dirs) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));

        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

And here's my coding for my command handler:

```
const fs = reqire('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`)
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the file names are the same as in your array?

Comment: We do need the contents of it, as you may not be assigning `module.exports`.

Comment: Yep. Well actually, they have .js at the end. Should I add that into my array?

Comment: @LoganDevine mk

Comment: no you don't need to add the js, but Logan is right, having the modules might help

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca: We do need the code in all of the command_handler and event_handler files as they may not have assigned it correctly.

Comment: I've edited it. It should show it now

Comment: oops I'm dumb. I spelt require wrong. I have a new error now. Mind helping me fix that too?

Comment: Make a separate question. @OrionB

Comment: @LoganDevine I'll just edit this question because I can only make a new question every 90 minutes

Comment: @OrionB: Please don't, StackOverflow is designed to be containing an archive of quality questions and editing this one will remove the old versions, and others with the same original problem cannot view the old one. Your second error is not in the post. EDIT: now it is

Comment: tbh, your event handler seems a little overcomplicated to me. Just require them in the index and be done with it

Comment: Ok I'll just change it back then and wait 90 minutes

Comment: The event is most likely not a function btw

Comment: @OrionB hit me up on discord if you want a quick answer to your question

Comment: Or, we can use SO chat

Comment: I don't know how to use SO chat so I'll just stick to discord. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody wondering about this question, it was just a typo. I spelled require wrong in my command_handler.